# Throwing exceptions in destructors - what are the downsides?

Tags: c++

What are the downsides of throwing exceptions in destructors?

Right now the only downside I can see is that it might halt freeing resources, are there other downsides to that?

Comment: Throwing exception while another exception is active (not caught) causes program to be immediately terminated.

Comment: Give an example where you think it is a good idea

Comment: @Rob I don't think it's a good idea but I can't see why it isn't, that's why I asked. Joker had a good point

Comment: Joker's point is THE point: destructors are called automatically while propagating an exception, and throwing in a destructor can cause a throw during a throw.

Comment: @leewangzhong: It's *a* point, but not *the* point; there are other reasons to avoid throwing destructors. In principle, you can structure your logic, or check `std::uncaught_exception()`, so that you can throw from a destructor with no risk of terminating the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the destructor is being called as a result of unwinding the stack to handle another exception, then throwing will terminate the program - you can't have more than one unhandled exception at a time.

If the destructor of an array element throws, then the destructors of the remaining elements won't be called. This could lead to memory leaks and other badness.

Throwing destructors make it difficult or impossible to provide exception guarantees. For example, the "copy-and-swap" idiom used to implement assignment with a strong exception guarantee (i.e. a guarantee that, if an exception is thrown, nothing has been changed) will fail:

```
thing & thing::operator=(thing const & t) {
    // Copy the argument. If this throws, there are no side-effects.
    thing copy(t);

    // Swap with this. Must have (at least) a strong guarantee
    this->swap(copy);
    // Now the operation is complete, so nothing else must throw.

    // Destroy the copy (now the old value of "this") on return.
    // If this throws, we break the guarantee.
    return *this;
}
```